# Eclipse/Android error: R can not be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, android, eclipse, error-handling, resources

I often randomly receive "R can not be resolved variable" errors, and when it happens I can never fix them unless I create a new project and copy and paste all the code. I think this shows that these are not errors from my code. I have cleaned the projects, restarted eclipse, my computer, and even reinstalled Eclipse, but none of those work.

I Have noticed that the gen file (Generated auto file) does not contain any file. I have not deleted them my self and this has frequently happened before.

I know that many people has posted questions on this topics but they have never worked for me and they usually receive low rating so not many people comments on them either. Also if it requires cmd or terminal, please give the commands for Windows, Linux/Mac. I use Mac. I have recently installed GooglePlayService in the SDK although it worked after I installed it.
I am very sorry for lack of useful information, as I have no idea what the issue is.

Here are some of my screen shots to show MainActivity.java, Package explorer and res.values.strings.xml.
[image: Package explorer shows that it has given my projects error and they are all located in the MainActivity.java file]

[image: My MainActivity.jar file showing error on R.]

[image: My res.values.strings.xml file]

I apologize for describing the situation in a confusing way but I tried my best, please tell me what you find confusing if you do find this confusing.

Aftr all Thank You Very Much!!!

Comment: have you tried clean&build  ?

Comment: There is something wrong with your XML files, solve it and then try to clean your project.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't think I have made a miss take in my xml as it always happens to all my projects in my workspace in a single moment. So, how can I make a miss take on all of my xml at once? I personally think it is an eclipse's bug. But I also think it is xml's fought but which file? resource? manifest? layout? I am terribly sorry, but please can you be more specific? But thank you very much for helping!!! :)

Comment: @WantingtobeanAndroidDevelor Inside `AndroidManifest.xml` file, is `package="com.example.maps"` still set inside `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.maps" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >`? Because this attribute (`package`) is used to define the location of automatically generated `R` class.

Comment: I think the Manifest is fine, I am too much of a noob to 100% understand what you said but I will put the screenshot of the manifest on the question (I'm sorry but for some reason, I can not upload any more image X( ;

Comment: It is better to paste the code, not screenshots of it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your "gen" folder is empty. It should contain R.java

[1]

Try this:

-Right click your project

-Select properties

-Select Java Build Path

-Click add Folder

-Select the gen folder

-Click OK

[2]

if [1] doesn't work

Check your Res folder for any errors in your XML files, if one of the files has errors, then the R file will not be built

Answer (score 0):

This error was caused by a bug on the Eclipse where even, if you click on re-build it does not regenerate the resource file.

To fix this, even if your eclipse claim that it is the latest version, you should go on the homepage and manually reinstall the latest eclipse with ADK or just install the android studio